# Python Writing .csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
data=open('c:/Users/Envy x360/Documents/Python Lesson1/result.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
csv_data=csv.reader(data)
data_list=list(csv_data)
#print(data_list)
dd=len(data_list)
#dd=dd-1
#print(dd)
student_result=[]#*dd
for kk in data_list[0:(dd)]:
    gg=[kk[0],kk[13]]
    student_result.append(gg)
print(student_result)
file_open=open('result_to_announce.csv', 'w', newline='') 
with file_open:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(file_open, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerows(student_result)
    file_open.close
```

The code before file write does exactly what it is expected to do with following output. It prints `student_result` correctly:

```
[['Student Name', 'Marks Obtained '], ['Hajra Masood', '218'], ['Anas Ikram ', '217'], ['Attiya Ahsan', '197'], ['Daniya Batool ', '221'], ['Haaris Chauhry', '217'], ['Anaum Fatima', '200'], ['Qaiser Ali Afandi', '209']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Envy x360\Documents\Python Lesson1\csvediting.py", line 14, in <module>
    file_open=open('result_to_announce.csv', 'w', newline='')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'result_to_announce.csv'
```

However, it gives permission denied error as shown above in the output and creates an empty file with name `result_to_announce.csv`,
I was expecting it to write the 'student_result' - which is a list of lists - into "result_to_announce.csv"

What's wrong with the code?
Why is it not writing 'student_result' into the file.

Comment: You probably have that file open in excel, which locks the file and prevents other programs from changing it

Comment: Could you share your input csv?

Comment: `file_open.close` doesn't close the file because missing () besides it's not useful in a with block

Comment: @user3431635 here is the link of input csv file  https://filebin.net/j5ve5zr0zj87rbf3